# Can't get a handle on styles in a included text file

Tags: text, include, styles

I am using basiclightbox to show text from an external txt file.

It works, but I can't apply styles and size to the result.

I've done this:

```
    document.querySelector('button.html1001').onclick = () => {

    basicLightbox.create(`
    </div>
    <h1><p> 
    <object data="test.txt"></object>
    </p></h1>
    </div>

    `).show()
    }
```

and

```
    <h1><p> 
    <object data="test.txt"></object>
    </p></h1>
```

and tried including styles in the text file, but this is the result of the popup:

```
    <h1><p> <br><br><br>
    <br>
    Testing text for testing
    <br>
    </p><h1>
```

It pops up with a black background and no style applies to the text.

Anyone have any ideas how to apply styles and background color to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was a style problem was problem with the lightbox code.

Have the code working with just:

```html
<object data="test.html">
```

But I still can't figure out how to change the size of the popup box.

Tried a bunch of stuff:

```html
<object data="test.html" width="400" height="400">
```

and

```html
<div id="cont">
  <object id="obj" width="" height="" data="test.html"></object>
<div>
```

and

```html
<div>
  <object width="600" height="900" data="test.html"></object> 
<div>
```

CSS

```css
div {
  height:600px;
  width:900px;
}
```

and some others, no luck.

Comment: Figured it out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I made a typo in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#obj").width($("#cont").width());
  $("#obj").height($("#cont").height());
});
```

```css
div#cont {
  height: 600px;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">
  <object id="obj" width="400" height="400" data="test.html"> 
  </object>
<div>
```

Comment: Please write only one answer which is more correct. That'll help other people as well.